# MySQL - Finding record that is leading to a duplicate entry in referenced table based on record number from error message

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have this query:

```
INSERT INTO `product`(`id`, `active`, `barcode`, `code`, `manufcode`, `manufname`, `name`, `taxid`, `unitname`, `pantheon_code_list`) 
                                             SELECT `id`, `active`, `barcode`, `code`, `manufcode`, `manufname`, `name`, `taxid`, `unitname`, `pantheon_code_list` FROM product_sync
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                    id = product_sync.id, 
                    active = product_sync.active, 
                    barcode = product_sync.barcode, 
                    manufcode = product_sync.manufcode, 
                    manufname=product_sync.manufname, 
                    name=product_sync.name, 
                    taxid=product_sync.taxid, 
                    unitname=product_sync.unitname, 
                    pantheon_code_list=product_sync.pantheon_code_list
```

I have a product_tr table that has a foreign key on product(id) and when I run above query (in phpMyAdmin) I get this error:

```
#1761 - Foreign key constraint for table 'product', record '526' would lead to a duplicate entry in table 'product_tr', key 'PRIMARY'
```

Now the question is how to find which record it is based on **record '526'** from the error message?

Or is there any mechanism like query a hint in MySQL so I get more details about the row that is causing this constraint violation?

Comment: What is your primary key in the `product` table? Do you have any rows where said primary key = 526? Do you have another table named `product_tr` (perhaps updated by a trigger on `product`?)

Comment: @Pepper, actually you were right! The product table has 2 unique columns so one of those keys has 526 as a value and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is producing an update that wants to change the value of one of those records to another ID.